# Regular Expression to Escape Lines with Comments

Tags: java, regex

I have used the regular expression `//.*|(\"(?:\\\\[^\"]|\\\\\"|.)*?\")|(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/` to escape out the comment lines and it works well but it is stuck over the line `if (broper.equals("//BR") && brlnum.equals("0"))` and treated it as comment line and escape out it.

What correction is required?

Comment: I think you need to use your regex inside a recursive function that is used to determine if you are inside quotes or not

Comment: @moon i have got this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code/8634091#8634091.  is it possible by changing the regular expression above so that it become able to avoid the matching in string?

Comment: I take it you want to match all comments, ie `//...` until the end of line and block comments `/* ... */`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit risky and would fail if comments themselves could contain an odd number of quotes. But if that's not a concern, you could go looking for `//`s that are followed by an even number of quotes, thereby ensuring that you're not inside a string at this moment:

```
//(?:[^"\r\n]*"[^"\r\n]*")*[^"\r\n]*$|/\*.*?\*/
```

The second alternative matches standard, unnested `/*...*/` comments.

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("//(?:[^\"\r\n]*\"[^\"\r\n]*\")*[^\"\r\n]*$|/\\*.*?\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: @Pietzcker o thanks for response, but it is not the general case actually my basic requirement is that i have to remove the comment of this type  `String str = srclines[lineNum];// skip the comments` means can be after seprator(;).

Comment: Have you tried this regex? Is it not working? If so, what text is it failing on?

Comment: @Pietzcker actually  I want that if comment character is coming within double quote then it should be ignored otherwise it should be processed for removing comment.e.g. `if ("\\BR".equals(str) && !otherString.contains("\\BR") // Condition to skip` Then remove only // Condition to skip

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly what this regex does. That's why I asked if you tried it at all.

Comment: @Pietzcker   `String s= "if (broper.equals(\"//BR\") && brlnum.equals(\"0\"\"))";
  String regex = "//(?:[^\"\r\n]*\"[^\"\r\n]*\")*[^\"\r\n]*$|/\\*.*?\\*/";
  String str = s.replaceAll(regex, "");`   this code results a string  `if (broper.equals("` actually that should not replaced by regular expression, i want. yeah here i have taken odd number of quotes but this could be in test cases.

Comment: That's invalid Java code (but OK, even if the extra quote were correctly escaped, the regex would still not pick this up). It is possible to fix this, but the regex would become very unwieldy.