# Java: Strip Slashes and Stars from Block Comments using Regex

Tags: java, regex, comments

I am working on a personal project where I need to extract the actual comments from an input string like this.

Case 1: `/* Some useful text */`

Output: `Some useful text`

Case 2: `/*** This is formatted obnoxiously**/`

Output: `This is formatted obnoxiously`

Case 3:

```
    /**

    More useful
information

    */
```

Output: `More useful information`

Case 4:

```
/**
Prompt the user to type in 
the number. Assign the number to v
*/
```

Output: `Prompt the user to type in the number. Assign the number to v`

I am working in Java and I have tried to replace `/*` and `*/` using naive method such as `String.replace` but since a comment can be formatted in different ways like above, the `replace` method seems not to be a viable approach to do this. How can I achieve the above outputs using regex?

[Here](http://pastie.org/private/gb4genjs0lzbzjgttkdrg#23,41) is the test comment file that I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like :

```
"/\\*+\\s*(.*?)\\*+/"
```

And dot should match also new lines:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*+\\s*(.*?)\\*+/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**EDIT**

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*+\\s*(.*?)\\*+/", Pattern.DOTALL); 
 Matcher m = p.matcher("/*** This is formatted obnoxiously**/");
 m.find();
 String sanitizedComment = m.group(1); 
 System.out.println(sanitizedComment);
```

Comment: `.` doesn't match new-lines in Java (not by default anyway, not sure if there's a way to set that). You need `(.|\n)`

Comment: @Dukeling: There is a way to set it in Java (DOTALL option). It is not a good idea to write `(.|\n)`, since you might miss out some characters. `.` excludes more than just `\n` in Java.

Comment: @Dukeling  nhahtdh is right , i've updated my answer to show you how you can make dot to match new lines

Comment: @Stephan that didn't work. I got `IllegalStateException` because there were no matches.

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*+\\s*(.*?)\\*+/",
       Pattern.DOTALL);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(matchedComment);
     String sanitizedComment = m.group();
     System.out.println(sanitizedComment);`

Comment: @Stephan, I did as you said, and everything works before the highlighted file in the code that O have uploaded [here](http://pastie.org/private/5hjraugtci52u43rvcuw#29-31)

Comment: @NullGeo i do not get it... for me it works :  String test = "/** "+System.getProperty("line.separator")
     +" Estimate the square root and assign it to x_0 "+System.getProperty("line.separator")
     +" */";
   
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*+\\s*(.*?)\\*+/", Pattern.DOTALL); 
   Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
   boolean a = m.find();
   String sanitizedComment = m.group(1); 
   System.out.println(sanitizedComment);

Comment: @Stephan But you're using strings without newlines in you test cases. Try it with newlines. [Here](http://pastie.org/private/gb4genjs0lzbzjgttkdrg#23,41) is the comment file I am using

Comment: @NullGeo i am using new lines : System.getProperty("line.separator") output the string if you don't believe me

Comment: @Stephan, sorry about that. In fact it was working like you said. But look the problem is that, my other regex for finding comment is giving me error values. 

I used the regex from this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code
to find block comments but for the test file, it's outputting
`"Find the square root of "
"%lf"
`
Highlighted lines are being taken as comments: http://pastie.org/private/5hjraugtci52u43rvcuw#26,40
Anyway better way to get block C-style block comments using regex?

Comment: @NullGeo if the regex from that question didn't work out for you did you try using the one provided by me or Keppil ? maybe they will have better results

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("/\\*+\\s*|\\s*\\*+/", "");
```

**EDIT**

To also get rid of newlines you could do something like:

```
String regex = "/\\*+\\s*|\\s*\\*+/|[\r\n]+";
String newString = oldString.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Comment: Awesome, It worked. Thanks!
Now I have one more question, I am using the following escaped string for finding comments in the file. 
`//.*|(\"(?:\\\\[^\"]|\\\\\"|.)*?\")|(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/`

How can I make it so that it will only find /* ... */ comments and not single line comments ( // ... ) ?

Comment: Hmm, looks like it does not work for cases like this:

        `/**

 Prompt the user to type in the number. Assign the number to v

 */`

This thing not letting me blanks line I will update the question.

Comment: @NullGeo: To get rid of the newlines I would just add a `.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "")`

Comment: @Keppil: You should make a second pass to remove the line separators.  And don't just remove them; you may end up running words together.  What you want to do is normalize the remaining whitespace (e.g. `.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`).  As for the `line.separator` property, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/247597/20938) for a discussion of its disutility.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Sure, if line feeds need to be replaced by a space, then a second pass is needed. There might be other small adjustments that need to be made depending on OPs use case, but I think it is fairly trivial to tweak the code above to fit such extra demands though.

Comment: No worries.  My biggest objection is to your use of the `line.separator` property.  There's no reason to expect all line separators in a given file to be the same as the current platform's default (or more accurately, what Java *thinks* is the platform default).  If you're on a Windows machine and the file contains only Unix-style separators, you'll be trying to match `\n` with `\r\n`, so nothing will happen.  Other way 'round, you'll remove all the `\n`s and leave the `\r`s in place.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Fair enough, changed to a more general approach.