# Regular expression finding empty comments in code

Tags: java, regex, search, comments

i am looking for a regular expression which only finds empty java comments like the following one:

```
/**
 * 
 */
```

Eclipse creates those when e.g. generating a serial version id... There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code) about finding all comments however i didn't manage to adapt the regex to only "filter" out the empty ones.

```
//.*|("(?:\\[^"]|\\"|.)*?")|(?s)/\*.*?\*/
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\/\*\*[\s\t\r\n]*[ \*]*[\s\t\r\n]*\*/
```

Should match any string which starts with /**, ends with */ and contains only line breaks, spaces or asterisks in between.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't

```
"\\s*/[*]{2}[*\\s]*[*]/\\s*"
```

together with the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag suffice?

It starts with whitespace (optional), then comes `/**` then there is only whitespace and `*` followed by `*/` optionally followed by more whitespace.

This is how it looks:

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/U2oBdIy1YR2dbDDm)

Comment: Thanks for the link to debuggex - din't know that until now. Seems quite helpful especially for a regex padawan like me :-)