# Massive remove of Javadoc empty comments in Eclipse project (at beginning of file only)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, javadoc, code-cleanup

I have many empty Javadoc comments at beginning of many Java files in my project.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.name.app
// etc. etc.
```

How to remove all of them using Eclipse?

Comment: Take a peek [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078528/tool-to-remove-javadoc-comments) (as a starting point...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression finding empty comments in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471230/regular-expression-finding-empty-comments-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

I found the required regex ...

With Search menu, File, put this in Containing text with "Regular expression" checked :

```
\A/\*\*(\s|\*)+\*/
```

Hope it helps for others.

Comment: Better use `\A/\*\*[\s*]+\*/` - it is more efficient.