# Regular expression- prefix and suffix without a specific string

Tags: java, regex

I'd like your help with the following problem.

I'm trying to define a regular expression which represent a valid comment in Java.

For that I want a prefix: `"/\*"` + Everything including new lines and tabs BUT not another `"\*/"+` a suffix `"*/"`

I tried this one: `"/\*"[^"\*/"]"\*/"` but it does not work. It takes `/*fdfsd */ */` as one valid comment

What should I do?

Comment: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html; have you tried googling?

Comment: And the feature you want is the 'non-greedy' operator (which Java calls a reluctant matcher) here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: What if in code there is string that contains `/*...*/` like `String s = "/*wassup*/";`? Do you want to find it or should you ignore it?

Comment: @Pshemo: I took care for a valid strings already.

Comment: @crownedzero: I did not find it there

Comment: @Jozef interesting thread here; quite possibly a perfect match doesn't exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
yourString.matches("/[*]((?![*]/).)*[*]/")
```

this will match at start `/*` and `*/` at end. In the middle I am using [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to test if character (represented by dot) is not first `*` in `*/`. Of course it involves little backtracking so performance may be improved but for now it would do the trick.