# Ignore java comments with JFlex

Tags: jflex

Hi I am trying to ignore java comments using JFlex but I can't manage to make it working, I always have an error in execution. I used these two lines:

```
commentary = "//"[\r\n]*(\r|\n|\r\n)
<YYINITIAL> {commentary}    {}
```

I also tried different things like `commentary = [/][/].*` but without success.

Comment: [java comment regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

> commentary = (/*([^*]|[\r\n]|(*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))**+/)|(//.*)

Please try this