# regex to match all comments //, /* */

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write regex to find all of the comments in a given file. The comments I should handle is multyline commnes such as

```
/* comments.
is multiline comment*/
```

or

```
// one liner comment.
```

I searched in few places, and found some answers. ([one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code))  and I managed to write something that answers most of my needs:

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/|//.*\n?)
```

The only thing that is wrong with my code that it catches comments inside of strings. for example

```
String str = " hey, // I'm not a comment "
```

my code get the "I'm not a comment " **but it shouldn't.**
I tried several things, such as negativelookahead and lookbehind, but nothing seems to work.

Is there any way of doing what I want?/
thanks.

**Edit:**
The language I'm using is python

Comment: in this case add the python tag to your question.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse programming languages. As you have noticed, regular expressions are unable to do this. This is a hard limitation, there is no work-around and every solution that tries to do it anyway will be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, consider using a parser instead (to take into account nested comments, etc.). That being said, you could use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` construct if it's supported (you did not specify your programming language):

```
"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
'[^']+'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
(?|
    //(?P<comment>.+)
|
    /\*(?P<comment>[\s\S]+?)\*/
)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/50xaQs/1).

Comment: I'm writing in python.
I don't know this syntax and it doesn't work if I'm trying to use your code in my program (probably because you wrote for another language). 
is there something like this for python as well?

Comment: There is, use the newer [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (`pip install regex`) and use verbose mode for the regex above.